# IProblem installing R XML package on windows

Tags: r

I`m keen to install the latest version of the R XML package on Windows which is not on CRAN

From other stackflow questions I have downloaded the relevant zip file XML_3.9-4.1.zip
but need some step by step help

I have tried running

```
install.packages("C:\Users\pssguy\Downloads\XML_3.9-4.1.zip", repos = NULL, type="source")`
```

and get error

```
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "C:\U"
```

Should I be unpacking the zip first?

There also seems to be a command mode option. Is that better and if so, what directory should I be in before and what would be exact code

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\ is used to denote that you want to escape the following character in strings.  Replace all of the \ in the path to the file with either \ or /

So change `"C:\Users\pssguy\Downloads\XML_3.9-4.1.zip"` to `"C:\\Users\\pssguy\\Downloads\\XML_3.9-4.1.zip"` or `"C:/Users/pssguy/Downloads/XML_3.9-4.1.zip"`

Comment: Thanks Dason. Big slip.. however now i get the error  installation of package ‘C:/Users/pssguy/Downloads/XML_3.9-4.1.zip’ had non-zero exit status //

Comment: I belatedly discovered the "Install package from local zip file" option. Seems to work fine now